# How to modify a character variable in R

Tags: r

I do not know how to deal with the length of a character variable. The data frame is as below:

```
   trr_id_code wl_id_code listing_ctr_code listing_ctr_code2 listing_ctr_zip
1      210914     485166            10695             10695      00919-1227
2          NA     762922            10695             10695      00919-1227
3          NA     801499            10695             10695      00919-1227
4       86627     481932            10695             10695      00919-1227
5          NA     598994            10695             10695      00919-1227
6      149324     128474            10695             10695      00919-1227
```

I try to modify the listing_ctr_zip variable (00919-1227) to be 00919.

I try to use like

```
zip <- character(data$listing_ctr_zip, length=5)
```

It seems totally wrong. 
I know this problem may be very easy, but can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the terrible format.

Comment: I think you want `?substr` - e.g. `substr("00919-1227", 1, 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to truncate your string you can use strtrim() as follows...

```
zip <- strtrim(data$listing_ctr_zip, 5)
```

This will choose the first 5 characters of your string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sub()` to remove the dash and the numbers that follow it.

```
sub("-[0-9]+$", "", data$listing_ctr_zip)
# [1] "00919" "00919" "00919" "00919" "00919" "00919"
```

The regular expression `-[0-9]+$` tells the `sub()` function to replace

- A literal `-`
- followed by one or more digits `[0-9]+`
- starting from the end `$`

with the empty string `""` in `data$listing_ctr_zip`